# Proving the uniqueness of an unbiased estimator

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, statistical-inference, parameter-estimation

Let $X$ be a random variable having pmf:

\begin{array}{ll}
   p(x)=2 \theta \ \ \ \text{if} \ x=-1 \\
   p(x)=\theta^2  \  \  \text{if} \ x=0  \\
   p(x)=1-2\theta-\theta^2 \ \ \text{if} \ x=1\\
       \\
\end{array} 
where $\theta \in [0,\sqrt{2}-1]$.

Show that there is one and only one unbiased estimator of $(\theta+1)^2$ based on a single observation.

I have been able to construct an unbiased estimator but I am failing to prove its uniqueness.

Define $I=1 \  \text{if} \ \ {x=0}\ \text{or} \ {x=-1}$ 
and $0$ otherwise.
$E(1+I)=1+P(X=0)+P(X=-1)=(\theta+1)^2$
But how to show that it is the only unbiased estimator?

I think if we can prove that $1+I$ is UMVUE then I think uniqueness is implied.

Comment: No, proving it is the UMVUE would not prove uniqueness. Rather, UMVUE would be proved from uniqueness of the unbiased estimator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $f(X)$ is an unbiased estimator of $(\theta+1)^2$. Then for any $\theta\in[0,\,\sqrt{2}-1]$
$$
(\theta+1)^2=\mathbb E[f(X)]=2\theta f(-1)+ \theta^2 f(0)+(1-2\theta-\theta^2)f(1).
$$
Rewrite this as following: for any $\theta\in[0,\,\sqrt{2}-1]$,
$$
\theta^2(f(0)-f(1)-1)+2\theta(f(-1)-f(1)-1)+(f(1)-1)=0.
$$
By Fundamental theorem of algebra, this polynomial can have infinite number of roots  only if all its coefficients are zero. So, $f(1)=1$, $f(-1)=f(0)=2$ give us the unique unbiased estimator $f(X)$.